# target only li and ignore children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html code with nesting li tags

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class="menu">
    <ul class="sub_nav">
        <li class="sub_menu"></li>
        <li class="sub_menu"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu">
    <ul class="sub_nav">
        <li class="sub_menu"></li>
        <li class="sub_menu"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

how select only li tag with class menu and deselect children with class sub_menu

```
 jQuery("li.menu :not('li.sub_menu')").click(function(
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active")
 })
```

Comment: It's not the selector you need to worry about per se, you're probably affected more by the click event bubbling up the DOM when clicking on a sub_menu list item. You can either stop the propagation on the sub_menu items, or check the target of the click event on the menu items.

Comment: @j08691  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this where you check if the item clicked is the selector element. If it isn't, you return false thereby stopping the event from bubbling up to the parent.

```js
$("li.menu").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target !== this) {
    return false;
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
li.menu.active {
  color: red;
}

li.sub_menu {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu">
    menu
    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
    menu
    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
$(".nav > li").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active")
});
```

You will still be selecting the other `li` nodes, but only as children of the parent `li`, which I don't imagine is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to define a default colour for the sub-menus via your CSS, like:

```
.menu, .sub_nav, .active .sub_nav{
  color: #555;
}
```

And then apply the active class only to the direct child of `.nav`.

That, and combining the JS code from @H77 (with targeting the `click` event to the top-level `li`) should do the trick.

See demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav > li.menu").click(function() {
    if (event.target !== this) {
      return false;
    }

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
li.active.menu {
  color: red;
}

.menu,
.sub_nav,
.active .sub_nav {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="menu">
    menu
    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">
    menu
    <ul class="sub_nav">
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
      <li class="sub_menu">submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```